# Apple Mach - 0 linker id error and Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, linker

My code was running correctly,I decided to rename cpp and hpp file and then       was not found, then I tried to change the build setting/library search path now  is found

but it is showing errors statingUndefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

> "Camera::find_circle(Camera::meniscus_finder_context&,
>   std::__1::deque >&)", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation).

This is my code :

```
 source.hpp
    #ifndef source_hpp
    #define source_hpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <list>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <deque>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <float.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>



/*!
 * @brief Models a camera which can provide an array of Rays
 *
 * dist_coeff: (k1, k2, p1, p2, k3, k4, k5, k6)
 */

    class Camera {
    public:
    Camera ();
    struct uint8_image_t {
        uint32_t w;
        uint32_t h;
        uint8_t *data;
    };
    typedef struct uint8_image_t uint8_image_t;

    struct int8_image_t {
        uint32_t w;
        uint32_t h;
        int8_t *data;
    };
    typedef struct int8_image_t int8_image_t;

    struct uint16_image_t {
        uint32_t w;
        uint32_t h;
        uint16_t *data;
    };
    typedef struct uint16_image_t uint16_image_t;

    struct int16_image_t {
        uint32_t w;
        uint32_t h;
        int16_t *data;
    };
    typedef struct int16_image_t int16_image_t;

    struct meniscus_finder_context {
        uint8_t bright_ring_threshold;
        double threshold_fraction;
        uint32_t cent_x;
        uint32_t cent_y;
        double_t cam_tilt;
        double_t edge_points_percent;
        double_t circle_x;
        double_t circle_y;
        double_t circle_r;

        uint8_image_t *input_image;
        uint8_image_t *mask_image;
        uint8_image_t *output_image;


        uint8_image_t *dilation_kernel;
        uint8_image_t *threshold_mask_image;
        uint8_image_t *temp_image;
        uint16_image_t *temp16_uimage;
        int8_image_t *kernel33v_image;
        int8_image_t *kernel33h_image;
        int16_image_t *grad_x_image;
        int16_image_t *grad_y_image;
        int16_image_t *outward_x_image;
        int16_image_t *outward_y_image;
        int16_image_t *dot_product_image;
    };

    struct edge_point_t {
        uint32_t i;
        uint32_t j;
        double_t v;
    };
    typedef struct edge_point_t edge_point_t;

     void find_circle(meniscus_finder_context &c, std::deque<edge_point_t           *> &points);    

    };


    #endif

    source.cpp
    #include "source.hpp"
    #include "cholesky.c"
    void Camera :: find_circle(meniscus_finder_context &c, std::deque<edge_point_t *> &points) {

    double_t _A_[9] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    double_t *A[3] = {&_A_[0], &_A_[3], &_A_[6]};
    double_t bx[3] = {0, 0, 0};
    double cos_tilt = cos(c.cam_tilt * M_PI / 180.0);
    double_t x, x2, xy, y, y2, wz, w;

    for(int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {
        edge_point_t *p = points[i];


        x = (double_t(p->j) - double_t(c.cent_x));
        y = (double_t(p->i) - double_t(c.cent_y)) / cos_tilt;
        w = p->v;
        x2 = x*x;
        y2 = y*y;
        xy = x*y;
        wz = w * (x2 + y2);

        bx[0] += wz;
        bx[1] += wz * x;
        bx[2] += wz * y;

        A[0][0] += w;
        A[0][1] += w * x;
        A[0][2] += w * y;
        A[1][1] += w * x2;
        A[1][2] += w * xy;
        A[2][2] += w * y2;
    }

    A[1][0] = A[0][1];
    A[2][0] = A[0][2];
    A[2][1] = A[1][2];

    solve(A, bx, 3);

    c.circle_x = 0.5 * bx[1];
    c.circle_y = 0.5 * bx[2];

     c.circle_r = sqrt(bx[0] + c.circle_x*c.circle_x +         c.circle_y*c.circle_y);
}
```

Comment: Any reason to spam the C tag for a C++ question?

Comment: actually my source code and header file was previously .c and .h file, then when i renamed it , the problem started and then < iostream> was not found, so I believe  there may be some correlation

Comment: So you wounder why two different languages are not compatible? Seriously: you should learn and practice **one** language at a time.

Comment: it was not my code, i am trying to modify it and right now I am in the C++ learning stage and reading some book suggested here. Do you have any idea about this problem?